# Trying to show that the interior of a given set is contained in another given set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

How do I show that *in the space of bounded continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to    $\mathbb R$*,

if there exists an open $\epsilon$-ball about $g$ that is contained in the set of functions that are positive-valued for all $x\in\mathbb R$,

then there exists an $\epsilon$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ $g(x)>\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $g(x) - c$ is in that open ball if $c$ is ...

Comment: Can I do this without defining another function? I don't quite understand your hint. Is this assertion somewhat equivalent to my statement:  if every function within $2\epsilon$ of $g$ is positive-valued, then $g(x)>\epsilon$ ?

Comment: Where do you get that $2$?

Comment: $g(x) - c$ is in the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $g$ iff $|c| < \epsilon$.  $g(x) - c$ is positive-valued for all $x$ iff $g(x) > c$ for all $f$.

Comment: Oh actually, I figured it out. The correct claim to show is: "If every function at most (i.e. including) ϵ from g is positive-valued, then g(x)>ϵ." To show this, we should initially set our ball to be of radius 2ϵ (or 1.5ϵ , etc.) instead.